# How can I implement a redirection for an anonymous user to a different view in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC if they don't have a required cookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-middleware, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

I am trying to restrict access to a specific URL **(/xyz)** for anonymous users who do not possess a specific GUID cookie. To handle this, I created a middleware that assigns the cookie via HttpContext for users who do not have it and are not authenticated using Identity Framework.

To implement this functionality, I wanted to utilize authorization filters and policies, but I am unsure how to redirect anonymous users without the required cookie to a custom view, different than the one used by Identity Framework default schema.

I have come across information suggesting that I can use IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler to solve my issue, but I am uncertain if this is the most appropriate solution. Additionally, I have seen others creating default cookie schemas for authentication, but I am unsure if these can be utilized for anonymous users, or how to assign them within a custom middleware.

Answer (score 1):

in the `XyzController/Index` action

```
if (noCookiePresent) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know I can redirect in a controller, but as I stated before I would like to utilize filters and processing in the middleware pipeline.